# SOAPUI: How to include Groovy script from an external file

Tags: groovy, soapui

How can I include groovy script from an external file?
[image]

I was tried to use:

```
def script = new GroovyScriptEngine('d:/soapui/payment.v2').with { 
    loadScriptByName( 'proxy.groovy' ) 
} 
this.metaClass.mixin script
```

But I get:

[image]

**Update**

Is there exists some possibility to pack my methods into jar or something like this, and use them from `Script TextArea`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [Groovy Test Step within SOAPUI](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/soapui/steps/groovy.html) to run the external script using the [GroovyScriptEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.1/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html).  I use [GroovyUtils](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/GroovyUtils.html) to find the Project's path so that the entire project can be kept in one place to aid source control, editing etc.

```
import groovy.lang.Binding
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

// location of script file is relative to SOAPUI project file.
String scriptPath = groovyUtils.projectPath + "/groovy/"

// Create Groovy Script Engine to run the script.
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptPath) 

// Load the Groovy Script file 
externalScript = gse.loadScriptByName("Utility.groovy")  

// Create a runtime instance of script
instance = externalScript.newInstance()

// Sanity check 
assert instance!= null

// run the foo method in the external script
instance.foo()
```

Comment: kinda late as wel, but happens when you export the project as a WAR? do you then need a groovy/ directory somewhere on the server?

Comment: I've not tried it, but if it held relative to the project it should work fine.

Comment: When i'm calling the method from the script using instance.gettestData("ReadPersonalDataTest.xls","dataSheet") , getting error "Missing Property Exception"

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your scripts in java (eclipse) and then export it as a jar and add in soapui.

Here are the step:

1. Create your code in java classes inside a package.
2. Right click on the package and export (select jar)
3. Add this jar to soapui /bin/ext folder (make sure to close soapui before this step)
4. restart soapui and now you can import and use the scripts inside soapui as below.
5. Create a groovy step and import the jar

   import package name.class name
6. Call the function as:

   class name.function name(parameter);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(getBinding()); 
gs.evaluate(new File('path/to/external.groovy').text);
```

Or even this:

```
evaluate(new File('path/to/external.groovy'));
```

Comment: I got `java.lang.Exception cannot get property 'requestContext' on null object` message for both. did you checked they before posting?

Comment: Check the code in your external file. Groovy engine ran it and got exception. Replace content of the external file with simple command to see how it works: log.info "Hello from external file"

Comment: When I placed the content of the external file into Script TextArea it work perfect. Problem occurs each time when I tried access to `log`, `context`, `requestContext`, `mockRequest` and `mockResponse` variables

Comment: Late comment to the thread, but you are not getting those variables in the "Load Script" tab. It needs to be in the tear-up or tear-down part.

Answer (score 0):

For the mixin error message, you might get rid of that if you use `ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()` and then `this.metaClass = null`. at the very beginning, before you start mixing in.