# SoapUI: how to include Java file (not Jar file) from external file

Tags: java, soapui

similar to "[SoapUI: How to include Groovy script from an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357680/soapui-how-to-include-groovy-script-from-an-external-file?rq=1)"

how can I import/include .java files in groovy step (not .jar file). The reason we want this is because if we create .jar and loose code somehow, any updates are very much problematic.

Thanks in advance.

using open source version of soapui

Comment: You may need to modify soapUI factory files to enable them to read .java files or other workaround is you can write required java code only in soapui.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java is 99% source compatible with Groovy, you could just rename your .java files to .groovy and the follow the instructions from your linked post.